# What is the technical term for the input used to calculate a checkdigit?

Tags: naming-conventions, terminology, checksum, isbn

For example:

```
code = '7777-5';
input = code.substring(0, 4);   // Returns '7777'
checkdigit = f(input);          // f() produces a checkdigit

assert.areEqual(code, input + "-" + checkdigit)
```

Is there a technical term for `input` used above?

<sub>Specifically I'm calculating [checkdigits for ISBNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number#ISBN-10), but that shouldn't effect the answer.</sub>

Comment: I don't think there is a specific technical term. Maybe *message*, or *data*, or whatever is most applicable from the domain itself.

Comment: @LukeH I couldn't find anything when googling so you're likely right, but I thought I'd check anyway.

Comment: I think your terms are confused.  If you read the linked spec carefully, you'll see that the thing you're checking is actually called the 'check digit'.  So the answer to your question would be 'check digit'.

Comment: @Dan - My understanding is that the `checkdigit` is the result of `f(input)`. I'm looking for what the technical term for `input` would be. I think I've got my terminology correct, but if I don't please correct me!

Comment: I've heard 'payload' for larger blocks of data that also has a checksum, but I'm not sure if that's appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

Is "original number excluding the check digit" technical enough? :)

Actually, it's often the case, as in the link you posted, that the check digit or checksum ensures a property about the *full* input:

> ...[the check digit] must be such that the sum of all the ten digits, each multiplied by the integer weight, descending from 10 to 1, is a multiple of the number 11.

Thus, you'd check the full number and see if it meets this property.

It's "backwards" when you're initially generating the check digit.  In that case, the function would be named generate_check_digit or similar, and I'd just name its parameter as "input".

Comment: I was hoping that the answer would be a fun word that could be thrown around at parties or used to win games of trivial pursuit - everyone cheering for the victor because they knew this obscure word. But "original number excluding the check digit" just doesn't have that ring to it...

Comment: @Gavin: I hear you, just don't see it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not sure if there is a well-known specific technical term for the input, what LukeH suggested (message/data) seems common enough.

Wiki for [checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum):

> With this checksum, any transmission error that flips a single bit of the message, or an odd number of bits, will be detected as an incorrect checksum

Wiki for [check digit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit):

> A check digit is a form of redundancy check used for error detection, the decimal equivalent of a binary checksum. It consists of a single digit computed from the other digits in the message.